# Rust grpc call to to a service written in c# on localhost either http or https

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rust

```
use gateway::notification_client::NotificationClient;
use gateway::LogRequest;
use prost_types::Timestamp;
pub mod gateway {
    tonic::include_proto!("log");
}
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut client = NotificationClient::connect("https://127.0.0.1:7082").await?;
    let current_time = chrono::Utc::now();
    let timestamp = Timestamp {
        seconds: current_time.timestamp(),
        nanos: 0,
    };
    let request = tonic::Request::new(LogRequest {
        service_message: "TestServer2".into(),
        service_name: "TextToSpeach".into(),
        time: Some(timestamp)
    });

    let response = client.save_log_to_rabbit(request).await?;

    println!("RESPONSE={:?}", response);

    Ok(())
}
```

I have a service written in C# where the Grpc server is located
[image]

I want to make a call to it from a rust service

When I use the https url I get:

```
Error: tonic::transport::Error(Transport, hyper::Error(Connect, Custom { kind: InvalidData, error: InvalidCertificate(NotValidForName) }))
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\gateway-client.exe` (exit code: 1)
```

When I use the http one I get:

```
Error: Status { code: Unknown, message: "h2 protocol error: http2 error: connection error received: endpoint requires HTTP/1.1", source: 
Some(tonic::transport::Error(Transport, hyper::Error(Http2, Error { kind: GoAway(b"", HTTP_1_1_REQUIRED, Remote) }))) }
```

I absolutely don't care about security, it's a learning project.

The C# service uses the default self-signed certificare for localhost

Answer (score 0):

```
use std::path::Path;

use gateway::LogRequest;
pub mod gateway {
    tonic::include_proto!("log");
}
use prost_types::Timestamp;
use tonic::transport::{Certificate, Channel, ClientTlsConfig};

use crate::gateway::notification_client::NotificationClient;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let cert_path = Path::new("C:\\path_to_your_project\\mycert.pem");

    // Load the server certificate
    let server_root_ca_cert = std::fs::read(cert_path)?;
    let server_root_ca_cert = Certificate::from_pem(server_root_ca_cert);

    let tls = ClientTlsConfig::new()
        .domain_name("localhost")
        .ca_certificate(server_root_ca_cert);

    // Update with the correct gRPC server address
    let channel = Channel::from_static("https://127.0.0.1:7082")
        .tls_config(tls)?
        .connect()
        .await?;

    let mut client = NotificationClient::new(channel);
    let current_time = chrono::Utc::now();
    let timestamp = Timestamp {
        seconds: current_time.timestamp(),
        nanos: 0,
    };

    let request = tonic::Request::new(LogRequest {
        service_message: "TestServer2".into(),
        service_name: "TextToSpeach".into(),
        time: Some(timestamp)
    });

    let response = client.save_log_to_rabbit(request).await?;

    println!("RESPONSE={:?}", response);

    Ok(())
}
```

Here is what I learned. I could not find a way to call my service without a certificate, so I used the certificate I knew my C# service was using.

win+r -> certmgr.msc -> root certificates

Find the one for localhost

double click -> details -> copy to folder

save it inside the project you need.

```
openssl x509 -in your_certificate.cert -out your_certificate.pem -inform DER -outform PEM
```

run this to get it to the right file format.

then configure the tls as shown in the code.

Any additional feedback and improvements are welcome